# Python - Remove all duplicate enteries from array

Tags: python, sql

I'm stuck with a problem.

I'm doing a SQL command to get some data. In the data, I created rows with an equal id. What I want is that I put all the data with the same ID in one array.
Here is what I have:

```
             ID Var1 Var2
    data = [[1,  A,   B],
            [1,  C,   D],
            [1,  E,   F],
            [2,  A,   B],
            [2,  C,   D],
            [2,  E,   F]]
```

As you can see, rows with an equal ID are put into a seperate array. This is what I want:

```
    data = [[1,  A,   B,   C,   D,   E,   F],
            [2,  A,   B,   C,   D,   E,   F]]
```

So I only want 1 ID and put all the values with that ID in 1 array.

This is my code:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT ID, Var1, Var2 FROM Test_Database")
result = mycursor.fetchall ()

data = []
for row in result :
data.append(row)

print(data)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: generally speaking - a sql database queried like you did should _never_ return the same id multiple times unless you have a composite key defined on the table (a key that spans multiple columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a list of list with the same structure:

```
lofl = []
for row in data:
    headers = [e[0] for e in lofl]
    if row[0] in headers:
        lofl[headers.index(row[0])].extend(row[1:])
    else:
        lofl.append(list(row))
```

`lofl` would be what you wanted in your description.

Comment: Error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'extend'  Am I making a dumb mistake?

Comment: Should be fixed now. `list()` can convert `set` and `tuple` to `list` type

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I can help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe make a dictionary that's keyed by the ID?

Something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data_dict = defaultdict(list)
for row in result:
    id_ = row[0]
    for item in row[1:]:
        data[id_].append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's results are returned as a tuple of values. Each time that you call `data.append()` you're just appending that row to the list, so you get a list containing the returned values of all of the rows in the table. What you're expecting is a list with unique row IDs as the first element and all of the possible other column values returned by the query as the rest of the elements.

Since you want unique IDs anyway you should use a dict:

```
data_results = {}
for row in results:
    row_id = query_results[0]
    if row_id in data_results:
        data_results[row_id]).extend(query_results[1:])
    else:
        data_results[row_id] = query_results[1:]
```

This should have the desired effect, albeit as a dictionary of lists instead of a list of lists. If you need the list to remain in a specific order then I'd suggest looking up details on OrderedDict.